# Telerik PropertyDefinition applied at runtime

Tags: c#, telerik

I'm trying to make a RadPropertyGrid that can take in an object at runtime and display it's properties. The issue that I'm having is that this data is decoupled and may have it's own property definitions that will need to be passed into the grid.

Is there a way to do this in C# so it can be executed at runtime, applying properties relevant to a data source that cannot be known by the PropertyGrid?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

Use behavior.
For example:

In .xaml:

```
    <UserControl.Resources>
                <x:Array x:Key="HiddenProperties" Type="sys:String">
                    <sys:String>CanEdit</sys:String>
                    <sys:String>IsEdit</sys:String>
                    <sys:String>DisplayName</sys:String>
                    <sys:String>Changed</sys:String>
                    <sys:String>Changing</sys:String>
                </x:Array>
    </UserControl.Resources>
...
    <telerik:RadPropertyGrid AutoGeneratePropertyDefinitions="True"
                             EditorTemplateSelector="{StaticResource CustomPropertyGridDataTemplateSelector}">
                        <i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                            <extensions:PropertyDefinitionFiltering HiddenProperties="{StaticResource HiddenProperties}" />
                        </i:Interaction.Behaviors>
                    </telerik:RadPropertyGrid>
```

In .cs

```
    public class PropertyDefinitionFiltering : Behavior<RadPropertyGrid>
    {
        private static RadPropertyGrid _PropertyGrid;

        #region HiddenProperties

        private static string[] _HiddenProperties;

        public static readonly DependencyProperty HiddenPropertiesProperty =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("HiddenProperties", typeof(string[]),
                                                typeof(PropertyDefinitionFiltering),
                                                new PropertyMetadata(OnSetHiddenProperties));

        public static string[] GetHiddenProperties(DependencyObject obj)
        {
            return (string[])obj.GetValue(HiddenPropertiesProperty);
        }

        public static void SetHiddenProperties(DependencyObject obj, string[] value)
        {
            obj.SetValue(HiddenPropertiesProperty, value);
        }

        private static void OnSetHiddenProperties(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            _HiddenProperties = (string[])e.NewValue;

            var propertyGrid = d as RadPropertyGrid;

            if (null == propertyGrid) return;

            _PropertyGrid = propertyGrid;
        }

        #endregion

        protected override void OnAttached()
        {
            base.OnAttached();

            AssociatedObject.Loaded -= OnLoaded;
            AssociatedObject.Loaded += OnLoaded;

            AssociatedObject.Unloaded -= OnUnloaded;
            AssociatedObject.Unloaded += OnUnloaded;
        }

        protected override void OnDetaching()
        {
            AssociatedObject.Loaded -= OnLoaded;

            OnUnloaded();

            base.OnDetaching();
        }

        protected void OnUnloaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            OnUnloaded();
        }

        protected void OnUnloaded()
        {
            _PropertyGrid.AutoGeneratingPropertyDefinition -= PropertyGridOnAutoGeneratingPropertyDefinition;
        }

        private void OnLoaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            _PropertyGrid = AssociatedObject;

            _PropertyGrid.AutoGeneratingPropertyDefinition -= PropertyGridOnAutoGeneratingPropertyDefinition;
            _PropertyGrid.AutoGeneratingPropertyDefinition += PropertyGridOnAutoGeneratingPropertyDefinition;
        }

        private static void PropertyGridOnAutoGeneratingPropertyDefinition(object sender, AutoGeneratingPropertyDefinitionEventArgs eventArgs)
        {
            PropertyDefinition propertyDefinition = eventArgs.PropertyDefinition;

            string propertyName = propertyDefinition.SourceProperty.Name;

            if (Array.IndexOf(_HiddenProperties, propertyDefinition.AutoGeneratedPath) > 0)
            {
                eventArgs.Cancel = true;
            }
            else
            {
                var descriptor = ((MemberDescriptor)(propertyDefinition.SourceProperty.Descriptor));

                /// Work with properties attribute, properties display name, etc
            }
        }
    }
```